# Special Character throwing 400 Bad Request for xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

Trying to pass multilingual words in query parameter and currently getting 400 Bad Request from the server.
Ive tried encodeURI and encodeURIComponent both of which didnt serve the particular scenario.

Comment: What is that special character, and where exactly is it? What is the method of the request, and the enc type?

Comment: español is an example for one of these .. where the n seems to be causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change the `charset` that is being passed. Try using `iso-8859-8` at first.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should base64encode your query parameters/payload if you're dealing with non-latin characters.

In javascript you can use [atoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) to decode from base64 and [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) to create a Base64-encoded ASCII string from a binary string.